# Looking for checkbox enable-disable coding techniques: tips to reduce JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I would ask help to encode the following restriction in Javascript but in a more optimal way, because my way is very long.

What I want to do is to mark 2 checkbox options, then disabling the remaining

```
<form>
  <div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="a" name="question1">a) Java <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="b" name="question1">b) C <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c" name="question1">c) C++  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d" name="question1">d) C#  <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is the JavaScript code that would improve, it worked the way I did, but I did not like, i think it's much code.

```
addEventListener('load',compruebacheck,false);  
    function compruebacheck(){
        document.getElementById('a').onchange = function() {
            if (document.getElementById('b').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('c').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('d').disabled = this.checked;

            }
            if (document.getElementById('c').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('b').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('d').disabled = this.checked;

            }
            if (document.getElementById('d').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('b').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('c').disabled = this.checked;
            }
        };
        document.getElementById('b').onchange = function() {
            if (document.getElementById('a').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('c').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('d').disabled = this.checked;       
            }
            if (document.getElementById('c').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('d').disabled = this.checked;                   
            }
            if (document.getElementById('d').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('c').disabled = this.checked;                   
            }
        };
        document.getElementById('c').onchange = function() {
            if (document.getElementById('a').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('b').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('d').disabled = this.checked;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('b').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('d').disabled = this.checked;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('d').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('b').disabled = this.checked;           
            }               
        };
        document.getElementById('d').onchange = function() {
            if (document.getElementById('a').checked)
            {
                document.getElementById('b').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('c').disabled = this.checked;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('b').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('c').disabled = this.checked;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('c').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById('a').disabled = this.checked;
                document.getElementById('b').disabled = this.checked;
            }
        };
    }
```

Sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm starting to learn JavaScript and I could not think of a better technique for my little experience in the language, I would appreciate some alternatives to find things that can be done using JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get your question answered? (If so, accept one?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.
Thanks for the neat question.

```
addEventListener('load',compruebacheck,false);
function compruebacheck() {
  document.getElementById('a').onchange = function() { func1(); }
  document.getElementById('b').onchange = function() { func1(); }
  document.getElementById('c').onchange = function() { func1(); }
  document.getElementById('d').onchange = function() { func1(); }
  func1();
  function func1() {
    var count4 = 
    (document.getElementById('a').checked ? 1 : 0) + 
    (document.getElementById('b').checked ? 1 : 0) + 
    (document.getElementById('c').checked ? 1 : 0) + 
    (document.getElementById('d').checked ? 1 : 0);
    document.getElementById('a').disabled = false; 
    document.getElementById('b').disabled = false; 
    document.getElementById('c').disabled = false; 
    document.getElementById('d').disabled = false; 
    if (count4 == 2) {
      if (!document.getElementById('a').checked) { document.getElementById('a').disabled = true; }
      if (!document.getElementById('b').checked) { document.getElementById('b').disabled = true; }
      if (!document.getElementById('c').checked) { document.getElementById('c').disabled = true; }
      if (!document.getElementById('d').checked) { document.getElementById('d').disabled = true; }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer what i need.